# Metric on two pointic set

Tags: metric-spaces

Find all metric on a set $X$ consisting of two points.

Obviously there is discrete metric $d$.  And $kd$  ($k>0$)  is also metric.

Can there any other metric  be given?

#### Edit :

What can you say when $X$ is any finite set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. If the set is $\{a,b\}$ ($a \neq b$) with metric D then  $D(a,b)$ is some positive number $c$. This makes $D$ equal to $c$ times the discrete metric.